# Why did my factor levels get reversed in logistic regression? (MNIST data)

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, logistic-regression, mnist

I'm taking a course where I'm using the [mnist](/questions/tagged/mnist) digit reader data to [predict](/questions/tagged/predict) digits with [logistic-regression](/questions/tagged/logistic-regression). I'm using the simplified data with only 2 outcomes, 2 and 7. But along the way it seems like the factor levels (2 and 7) got reversed?

To get to where I am:

```
library(dslabs)
data("mnist_27")
```

x_1 and x_2 are the values from the first two predictors (columns). Now to fit the `logistic model`:

```
fit_glm <- glm(y~x_1 + x_2, data=mnist_27$train, family="binomial")
p_hat_logistic <- predict(fit_glm, newdata=mnist_27$test)
y_hat_logistic <- factor(ifelse(p_hat_logistic > 0.5, 7, 2))
```

Here's where my problem arises. In the last line, why should the function predict 7 if `p_hat_logistic > 0.5`? In `mnist_27$test$y`, the factor levels are `2` & `7`. Since the first level is `2`, shouldn't we predict `2` if `p_hat_logistic > 0.5`? But that doesn't work, as it leads to a lower accuracy.

Comment: I'm not sure, but try adding `type="response"` in  the `predict` statement to predict on the probability rather than the log-odds scale ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstood the response in a logistic regression model through the `glm()`. According to the help page for `glm()`:

> For binomial and quasibinomial families the response can also be specified as a factor (when the first level denotes failure and all others success)

Since 2 comes before 7 then the model is providing regression coefficients on the log odds scale and positive values increases the odds of getting category 7.

Ben's comment is important though: You need to have predictions on the probability scale is you want to compare it to 0.5. Alternatively you should compare the predictions (on the log odds scale, i.e., with no `response` or `response="link"`) to 0 since log(0.5 / (1-0.5)) = 0

Answer (score 0):

It always predicts the second level, in your case, you can do the below and the results looks correct to me:

```
p_hat_logistic <- predict(fit_glm, newdata=mnist_27$test,type="response")
y_hat_logistic <- factor(ifelse(p_hat_logistic > 0.5, 7, 2))

table(y_hat_logistic,mnist_27$test$y)

y_hat_logistic  2  7
             2 82 26
             7 24 68

caret::confusionMatrix(y_hat_logistic,mnist_27$test$y)
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  2  7
         2 82 26
         7 24 68

               Accuracy : 0.75           
                 95% CI : (0.684, 0.8084)
    No Information Rate : 0.53           
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1.266e-10      

                  Kappa : 0.4976         

 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.8875         

            Sensitivity : 0.7736         
            Specificity : 0.7234         
         Pos Pred Value : 0.7593         
         Neg Pred Value : 0.7391         
             Prevalence : 0.5300         
         Detection Rate : 0.4100         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.5400         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.7485         

       'Positive' Class : 2
```